# How to run SQL query in different computer?

Tags: vb.net

I want to start the program with different user to execute an SQL command to get username and password verification test. But my code does not work.

```
Private Sub Btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_login.Click
    konek()

    cmd = New SqlCommand("select User_id, Username, Password from [dbo].[User] where Username = '" & Txtusername.Text & "' and Password ='" & Txtpassword.Text & "'", conn)

    baca = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    baca.Read()

    If baca.HasRows Then
        baca.Close()

        cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into [Login].[dbo].[Login_log] (User_id,Date_jam_in,Pc_short,ip) VALUES ('" & Txtusername.Text & "','" & DateAndTime.Now & "','" & Txtnamakom.Text & "','" & TxtIPAddress.Text & "')", conn)
        baca = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        MsgBox("Login Berhasil", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Success")

        Process.Start("cmd.exe" + Txtusername.Text + "Notepad.exe" + Txtpassword.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Sorry, username or password ora ene", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
    End If

    Txtpassword.Text = ""
    Txtusername.Text = ""
    Txtusername.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: In the If-block you forgot to call baca.Read(), close it and do something with the query.

Comment: What if my username is bob's  ? Use parameters! Open/close the connection as quickly as possible, you need it open for the least amount of time. Also, start looking at "using". As for your question, "my code is not work" is not very specific, what isn't working? Are you having an error?

Answer (score 0):

Close your READER then Read another one again for that another query you put in it then at the end of the process close the READER Again ('baca' is your READER)

```
Private Sub Btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_login.Click

     konek()
     cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT User_id, Username, Password from [dbo].[User] WHERE Username = '" & Txtusername.Text & "' and Password ='" & Txtpassword.Text & "'", conn)

     baca = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     baca.Read()


     If baca.HasRows Then
        baca.Close()

        cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into [Login].[dbo].[Login_log] (User_id,Date_jam_in,Pc_short,ip) VALUES ('" & Txtusername.Text & "','" & DateAndTime.Now & "','" & Txtnamakom.Text & "','" & TxtIPAddress.Text & "')", conn)

        baca = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        baca.read()

        MsgBox("Login Berhasil", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Sucses")
        Process.Start("cmd.exe" + Txtusername.Text + "Notepad.exe" + Txtpassword.Text)

        baca.close()
     Else
        MsgBox("Sorry, username or password ora ene", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")

     End If
        Txtpassword.Text = ""
        Txtusername.Text = ""
        Txtusername.Focus()

End Sub
```